# robotoslab light font in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: css, fonts

I am using opencart 2.0.1.1 and the I want to use the roboto slab light fonr in my website for product name and heading of featured and latest blog. I take the link from google font and add it to my header.tpl that is `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300,700,100&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` and also the css font family to add in stylesheet that is "robotoslab", serif; after applying it I found that the serif font is apply but robotoslab is not. Please help me in this matter and I am using Opencart 2.0.1.1 default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done and the solution is add this css codes to your stylesheet `

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'robotoslab';
  src: url('../fonts/robotoslab-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/robotoslab-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-regular.svg#robotoslab') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'robotoslab-bold';
  src: url('../fonts/robotoslab-bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/robotoslab-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-bold-webfont.svg#robotoslab-bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'robotoslab-light';
  src: url('../fonts/robotoslab-light-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/robotoslab-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/robotoslab-light-webfont.svg#robotoslab-bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}`
```

and add all the fonts folder inside the theme of your root directory